# MPAndroidChart real time graph c#

Tags: c#, android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying MPAndroidChart to plot real time data but when the graph moves using MoveViewToX(float xIndex) method sometimes the first value that is shown (and the label) in the current View disappear. This is the code:

```
//Adding entries
protected void AddEntry(int rssi, int i)
    {
        LineData data = linechart.LineData;
        if (data != null)
        {
            LineDataSet dataset = (LineDataSet)data.GetDataSetByIndex(0);
            if (dataset == null)
            {
                dataset = createSet();
                data.AddDataSet(dataset);
            }
            //Add new value
            data.AddXValue(i.ToString() + " ");
            data.AddEntry(new Entry(rssi, dataset.EntryCount), 0); 
            linechart.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            linechart.SetVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
            linechart.SetVisibleXRangeMinimum(10);
            //scroll to the last entry
            linechart.MoveViewToX(data.XValCount);
        }

    }
```

Dataset:

```
protected LineDataSet createSet() 
    {
        LineDataSet lineset = new LineDataSet(null, "Signal Power (dBm)");
       lineset.SetDrawCubic(false);
        //lineset.SetDrawFilled(true);

        lineset.Color = Color.Aqua;
        lineset.SetCircleColor(Color.DarkCyan);
        lineset.CircleSize = 3f;
        lineset.SetCircleColorHole(Color.DarkCyan);
        lineset.AxisDependency = linechart.AxisRight.GetAxisDependency(); 
        lineset.LineWidth = 2f;
        lineset.SetDrawValues(false);
        return lineset;
    }
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    p1:id="@+id/chart1"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="250dp" />
<ListView
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    p1:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    p1:id="@+id/list" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is what happens:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zl0l.png)
Thank You in advance.

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Basically, sometimes, when a new value is added, the value closest to the Y axis is not shown(the label containing its value on the X axis and the point showing its position on the graph disappear).